# publishing to Google Play: APKs are not allowed for this application

Tags: continuous-integration, google-play, continuous-delivery, codemagic

I want to build my app with codemagic and publish it to the google play store.

I used this tutorial: https://docs.codemagic.io/knowledge-base/google-play-api/

But I get this exception:

```
Publishing app-release.apk to Google Play
Google Play failed to upload artefacts. APKs are not allowed for this application.: {
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "APKs are not allowed for this application.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the Android App Bundle (`.aab`) on Google Play, not `.apk`

If it's simple Android application you should use `./gradlew bundleRelease` to generate `.aab` file

Comment: Thanks, I found an combobox in codemagic to change from .apk to .aab